Calculate average of last 5 last rows with Sheets formula
I'm looking for a formula to calculate an average of the results of the last 5 lines. It must meet the following conditions:

If there is only one line (line 2 as line 1 contains the labels), the result must be equal to
(E2xE1+F2xF1+G2xG1)/(E2+F2+G2)

If there are two lines, the result must be equal to
((E2+E3)xE1+(F2+F3)xF1+(G2+G3)xG1)/(E2+E3+F2+F3+G2+G3)

If there are three lines, the result must be equal to
((E2+E3+E4)xE1+(F2+F3+F4)xF1+(G2+G3+G4)xG1)/(E2+E3+E4+F2+F3+F4+G2+G3+G4)

If there are four lines, the result must be equal to
((E2+E3+E4+E5)xE1+(F2+F3+F4+F5)xF1+(G2+G3+G4+G5)xG1)/(E2+E3+E4+E5+F2+F3+F4+F5+G2+G3+G4+G5)

If there are five lines, the result must be equal to
((E2+E3+E4+E5+E6)xE1+(F2+F3+F4+F5+F6)xF1+(G2+G3+G4+G5+G6)xG1)/(E2+E3+E4+E5+E6+F2+F3+F4+F5+F6+G2+G3+G4+G5+G6)

If there are six lines, the result must be equal to
((E3+E4+E5+E6+E7)xE1+(F3+F4+F5+F6+F7)xF1+(G3+G4+G5+G6+G7)xG1)/(E3+E4+E5+E6+E7+F3+F4+F5+F6+F7+G3+G4+G5+G6+G7)

If there are seven lines, the result must be equal to
((E4+E5+E6+E7+E8)xE1+(F4+F5+F6+F7+F8)xF1+(G4+G5+G6+G7+G8)xG1)/(E4+E5+E6+E7+E8+F4+F5+F6+F7+F8+G4+G5+G6+G7+G8)

etc...


Here's my Sheets file with the expected results in column J. I'm not at all comfortable with formulas in Sheets.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=byrow(E2:G;lambda(Σ;if(counta(Σ)=0;;let(Λ;bycol(chooserows(E2:index(G:G;row(Σ));sequence(min(row(Σ)-1;5);1;-1;-1));lambda(x;sum(x)));
 average.weighted(E1:G1;switch(Λ;;0;Λ))))))



Thank you so much rockinfreakshow, it's work perfectly !!!!!!


You need sum of each col in the last 5 rows for each row multiplied by the headers divided by the sum of the last 5 rows. Essentially,

=SUM(SumOfEachCol(last5Rows)*headers)/SUM(last5Rows)


last5 of each range can be obtained with OFFSETing the given range by -4. For eg,  G7 becomes G3(7-4=3)
SumOfEachCol can be  obtained by BYCOL
BY(For) each ROW, get the last5 for that row, then calculate  the SUMPRODUCT of SumOfEachCol(last5(row)) and divide it by SUM(last5Rows)

=LET(
    header, E1:G1,
    rg, E2:INDEX(G:G,XMATCH(,G:G,1,-1)),
    last5, LAMBDA(rg, rg:OFFSET(rg,if(ROW(rg)>6,-4,-ROW(rg)+2),0)),
    sumOfCol, LAMBDA(col, SUM(col)), 
    sumOfEachCol, LAMBDA(row,BYCOL(last5(row),sumOfCol)),
    BYROW(rg,
     LAMBDA(row,SUMPRODUCT(sumOfEachCol(row),header)/SUM(last5(row)))
    )
)




1[E1]
2[F1]
3[G1]
Output





3
11
2.78571428571429



1
13
2.85714285714286



1
13
2.88095238095238




14
2.91071428571429


1
1
12
2.88571428571429




14
2.92857142857143


1
2
11
2.88571428571429


2
2
14
2.82432432432432


5
2
14
2.69135802469136



2
3
2.66666666666667




Another alternative using QUERY function, but it does not spill down. You have to enter the formula in cell say K2 and drag down;
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDEX(QUERY({E$2:E2 * E$1, F$2:F2 * F$1, G$2:G2 * G$1, ROW(A$2:A2)}, "Select Col4, (Sum(Col1) + Sum(Col2) + Sum(Col3)) Group By Col4 Order By Col4 Desc Limit 5 Label (Sum(Col1) + Sum(Col2) + Sum(Col3)) ''"),,2))/SUM(INDEX(QUERY({H$2:H2, ROW(A$2:A2)}, "Select Col2, Sum(Col1) Group By Col2 Order By Col2 Desc Limit 5 Label Sum(Col1) ''"),,2)))

.
The below Markdown Table shows the range E1:K11



1
2
3
Number of values
Average
Expected result
MY RESULT SET





3
11
14
2.785714286
2.785714286
2.785714286



1
13
14
2.928571429
2.857142857
2.857142857



1
13
14
2.928571429
2.880952381
2.880952381




14
14
3
2.910714286
2.910714286


1
1
12
14
2.785714286
2.885714286
2.885714286




14
14
3
2.928571429
2.928571429


1
2
11
14
2.714285714
2.885714285
2.885714286


2
2
14
18
2.666666667
2.824324324
2.824324324


5
2
14
21
2.428571429
2.691358024
2.691358025



2
3
5
2.6
2.666666667
2.666666667



